# beginner in GSM: develop GSM locator

Tags: gsm

i'm a beginner, and i trying build a GSM embedded device that could send SMS to a mobile phone, so that the phone can locate the location of the device.

I have searched this website for similar topic, what come to me is triangulation calculation.

My question is how do i know which tower the GSM device is near to, and how to connect to these three tower to calculate the location?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do cell triangulation, you need to know the geographic position of the cell towers.

Either you undertake a huge effort to build a cell tower inventory or you are the network operator. In practice, only the network operators render this service, some allowing to query locations via an interface. However, this is not standardized.

Comment: I found this website that provide free database for cellular map, could i use this to develop my application?

Comment: Yes, you could use it, to the extent the database covers the actual cell tower infrastructure. You may experience some white spots.

Answer (score 0):

you have to purchase GSM module. connect it with microcontroller

read at commands provided by manufacturer first.

there is a AT command for your application

try searching following in datasheet:

AT+CREG.

first configure module using this command.(refer your datasheet of gsm module).

then turn on engineering mode using command:

AT+QENG=2,1. (refer datasheet)

now it will give you automatically ncell,bcch,dbm,bsic,c1,c2,mcc,mnc,lac & cellid

it will give you this periodically or by query according to your command.

there are many websites that can triangulate device feeding them this info

i.e. opencellid.org/

i hope this helps!